# MVVM alternate events pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I currently have a hierarchy that looks like this

```
MainWindowViewModel
    TabViewModel
        EditorViewModel
            ReviewingServices
                ConflictFinder
```

The issue I'm running into is that `TabViewModel` wants to be notified of conflicts (from `ReviewingServices`) as well as other things. I *could* create public getters for all my dependencies and subscribe to whatever I want with `DependencyA.DependencyB.DependencyC += SomeHandler;` but that's rather messy. I'm finding myself creating far too many events that I wish to count. Essentially, I've created a messy web of events. I love the separation of responsibilities that I've created for every class but when every class has 2-3 events each it's rather difficult to maintain. I'm having no issues creating and maintaining events if the subscriber is only 1 level above. The mess comes when say `MainWindowViewModel` wishes to be notified of new reviews (published from `ReviewingServies`.

Is there a better of doing these types of events where a subscriber could want to subscribe to events that are deeply nested in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I really got your trouble, but I suggest to look at some kind of event aggregator. Try to check out the [Caliburn one](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2011/05/30/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-8-the-eventaggregator.aspx), but is not so different to implement one yourself. With this you name the event with a type and subscribe to it from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft Prism and their Event Aggregator

Answer (score 1):

Chaining `DependencyA.DependencyB.DependencyC` is generally considered breaking the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (you are effectively relying on a dependency of a dependency, etc).

I recently solved a similar design problem by using a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) defined by an interface such as `IMyOperationNameContext` which allowed me to share/inject the combined context of two ViewModels with/into a WinForms control which uses a third ViewModel and all of that without coupling the three models together directly.

Something like this (note how in the sample the `IAlbumContext` acts more as a proxy, but that's just because the sample is simplified):

```
interface IAlbumContext
{
    public AlbumInfo SelectedAlbum { get; set; }
}

class AlbumContext
{
    AlbumSelectionViewModel _model;

    public AlbumContext(AlbumSelectionViewModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }     

    public Album SelectedAlbum {
        get { return _model.Album; }
    }
}

class PhotoUploadDialog : Dialog
{
    public PhotoUploadDialog(IAlbumContext context, PhotoUploadViewModel viewModel)
    {
    }
}
```

While this solution worked for me and I like that it's with high cohesion and decoupled it's ultimately not massively scalable (e.g the number of such context interfaces can grow rapidly depending on the app). However with a more generic solution the trade-off is that the code gets harder to follow.